# How to paraphrase this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> The effects of the mechanization of women's work have not borne out
>   the frequently held assumption that new technology is inherently
>   revolutionary.

I am perplexed to understand the above sentence. Could anyone help me to paraphrase this sentence, that way I can understand this clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The effects of the mechanization of women's work*
>   = Whatever effects such mechanization may cause
>
> *[have not borne out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bear-out)*
>   = don't show
>
> *the frequently held assumption*
>   = that the assumption that is the commonly believed
>
> *that new technology is inherently revolutionary.*
>   = that new technology is essentially revolutionary is true.

---

NOTE: I simplified the tense a little to make it a little clearer. To stick to the original, it should've been *"haven't shown"*. I wrote this answer assuming that the phrasal verb **bear out** (to show that something is true or that someone is telling the truth) was the main confusion.